# how to reset the value from a field after 60 mins in postgresql-9.6?

Tags: postgresql

in my table, there are two fields fail_count and fail_count_timestamp.
fail_count field stores the count of login failed attempts and fail_count_timestamp will store the recent timestamp of the fail attempt.
so I want to resent the fail_count value after the timestamp crosses 60mins.

Comment: Don't use PostgreSQL 9.6. It is dangerous.

Comment: actually, the application has a dependency on the database version that's why they are not ready for the latest version. thank you for suggestion

Comment: Then don't use that application. It is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Do that whenever you record a failure:

```
UPDATE tab
SET fail_count_timestamp = current_timestamp,
    fail_count = CASE WHEN fail_count_timestamp
                         < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 hour'
                      THEN 1
                      ELSE fail_count + 1
                 END
WHERE id = 42;
```

When querying the table, you can return 0 for `fail_count` if the timestamp is too old by using a similar `CASE` expression.